# Thread Safety and code synchronization in java

Tags: java

I was reading about Thread Safety and code synchronization in java ..
I did this code in java . I do not like its output when it shows true or false in the output .

do you have any idea to remove the true and false from the output to improve my code performance ?

does my code works according to the Thread Safety and synchronization ?

thanks

```
public class B {

        public int numberOfTotalTickets=2;
        public int numberT;
        public String nameP;


        public boolean check(int numberOfTickets, String name) {
            numberT=numberOfTickets;
            nameP=name;
            if(numberOfTickets <=numberOfTotalTickets) {
                actionOk(nameP);
                return true;

            } else {
                actionNotOk(nameP);
                return false;
            }

        }

        public void actionOk(String nameP) {
        numberOfTotalTickets=numberOfTotalTickets-numberT;
        System.out.println("your booking is complete"+" "+ nameP);

        }

        public void actionNotOk(String nameP) {
            System.out.println("number of tickets available"+" "+ numberOfTotalTickets);
            System.out.println("sorry"+" "+ nameP +" " +"your booking is not complete because we have only"+" "+numberOfTotalTickets+" "+"tickets");

            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.check(2, "jack"));
        System.out.println(b.check(2, "sam"));

    }

}
```

my code's output is

```
your booking is complete jack
true
number of tickets available 0
sorry sam your booking is not complete because we have only 0 tickets
false
```

Comment: The printing of `true` and `false` has nothing to do with thread safety.

Comment: How can I remove them (true andd false) ? if I remove them I get error .. so how to improve the code ? thanks

Comment: Your `check` method returns a boolean value.  You are printing out that returned value in your `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding printing of true/false: You are printing the output of `check` function, because it is type of `boolean` and you call it inside `System.out.println`. Just call it directly, without `System.out.println`.

Regarding Thread Safety: Try to use `private` access modifiers when not requiring access from other classes. If I understand correctly what you want to achieve with this code (you just need to call `check` from outside), you can transform everything to `private` apart from your `check` method and by adding the `synchronized` keyword to this method, you are safe.

```
public synchronized boolean check(int numberOfTickets, String name) {
...
```

Comment: thank you .. do you mean I have to rewrite the following to private : ` public int numberOfTotalTickets=2; public int numberT; public String nameP;`

Comment: yes, but also private void actionOk, private void actionNotOk

Comment: When the Java interpreter executes an application it starts by calling the class's main method. It depends on how you are going to run your program and what you want to achieve. Till now, you are just trying to book tickets for two users.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not thread-safe.

```
public void actionOk(String nameP) {
    numberOfTotalTickets=numberOfTotalTickets-numberT;
    System.out.println("your booking is complete"+" "+ nameP);
}
```

If two threads are accessing the instance variables at the same time, then the wrong number of tickets could be returned.

Consider this

```
Thread1: read number of tickets as 2
Thread1: interrupted
Thread2: read number of tickets as 2
Thread2: assigns 2 tickets
Thread1: resumes and also assigns 2 tickets.
```

Both threads would see that 2 tickets are available.

Comment: The non-thread-safety even starts with the public fields of B.

Comment: thank you ..but I got an output which was correct as you can see in my topic  How do you think that I have to change?

Comment: The output is correct because you are making two synchronous calls to the method. Threads run independently. Try doing a thread tutorial, like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html